# Passing multi-value string consisting of TFS area paths to subreport in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, reporting, olap, multivalue

I'm having a problem with passing mulit-value argument to subreport. We have a report that is generating data from Team Foundation Server about velocity, burndown, bugs etc. The main report is pointing to a few subreports (for each team) were this measures are being done. On that 'Team' subreports we have next subreport for generating data for Bugs and with this I have problem (I'm getting subreport errors).

To calculate values that we want, we're passing an TFS AreaPath for this Bug subreport from main report level (it's a simple string eg. [Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].[Area2].&[-8426352345429395890]&[-7702890005762484781]) and it's working ok. Now on, we want to pass multi values so that Bug subreport will count Bugs for two or more Area Paths. Bug subreport is ready for that as when I generate it standalone I can choose more than one Area and it's counting and showing data properly. The only thing I have now is a problem how to pass multi-value string to this sub report so that it work properly.

We have something like this:

```
Main Report -> 'Team' Subreport -> Bugs Subreport
```

**On Main Report:**
Parameter 'BugAreaParam' with string [Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].[Area2].&[-8426352345429395890]&[-7702890005762484781] as value passed to 'Team' Subreport.

**On 'Team' Subreport:**
Parameter 'WorkItemAreaPath' passed to 'Bugs' subreport with value from BugAreaParam set as an expression: =Parameters!BugAreaParam.Value

**On Bugs Subreport:**
Parameter 'WorkItemAreaPath' that is taking value and generates data. It is a multi-value and when I generate it as standalone report I can pick multi-value to generate data.

The question is, how to properly set parameter 'BugAreaParam' on Main report so that it pass two or more values eg. [Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].[Area2].&[-8426352345429395890]&[-7702890005762484781] and [Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].[Area2].&[-55555]&[-44444] and Bugs subreport will generate Bugs from this two Areas?

Thanks you very much for any help!

BR,
Damian

Answer (score 0):

You could try Edwin's solution in [this case](https://forums.asp.net/t/2025016.aspx?Pass%20Multi%20value%20parameter%20to%20subreport%20in%20dirll%20through%20report%20ssrs):

1. Make sure that the parameter in the subreport is set to allow
   multiple values.
2. Make sure you are passing the parameter from the main report to the
   subreport as  **[@paramName]** and not **"=Parameters!ParamName.Value(0)"**
   as this indicates to retrieve only the first value.
3. Set the subreport parameter to visible and ensure manually
   selecting/inputting multiple values returns appropriate results.
4. If all else fails, try using a formula like this 
   **=Split(join(Parameters!ParamName.Value,","),",")**  which creates a comma separated list of the parameter values and then splits it out
   into an array.